# pytest marks test as PASSED after an assertion error

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I am trying to write a test using [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/). I have a service which can register a listener with an event name and a callback function. For a period it generates data and invoke the callback passing it as an argument. Basically I need to evaluate some assertions inside the callback, but even if the assertion fails `pytest` says that test is passed.

```py
def mytest():
    service = MyService()

    def on_data(data):
        assert False

    def on_end():
        print('All done')

    service.on('data', on_data)
    service.on('end', on_end)

    service.start()
```

When running this using `pytest`, I get:

```sh
ERROR assert False
Traceback [...]
    assert False
AssertionError: assert False

All done
PASSED

============================== 1 passed in 10.67s ==============================
```

Why is test marked as PASSED?

Comment: Please show `MyService` code

Comment: Does the service run in another process? In this case the assertion will not get passed to pytest.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen MyService spawn multiple threads, the callback is executed in one of these threads. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Yes, that is probably the problem. I have no experience with testing multi-threaded code, but this should be a known use case.